# MySQL: Unable to call function from within SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select

I have created a function called removeYear in SQL. The function is defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION removeYear(passedTitle CHAR(255), passedYear CHAR(100))
RETURNS CHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
```

The function works properly. The problem is that I am unable to call it from within a SELECT statement using one of my column names. For example:

```
SELECT movieid, title
FROM movies
WHERE movieid = 40;
```

Works.

```
SELECT movieid, title, removeYear("bluh", movies.year)
FROM movies
WHERE movieid = 40;
```

Works.

```
SELECT movieid, title, removeYear(movies.title, movies.year)
FROM movies
WHERE movieid = 40;
```

Gives the following error:
**Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'field list'**.

I have simply *no* idea what is causing this error. movies.title is a valid column. I have tried calling the function with every other column in my table, and those all work fine. For example:

```
SELECT movieid, title, removeYear(movies.movieid, movies.year)
FROM movies
WHERE movieid = 40;
```

Executes just fine.

EDIT:
In my frustration, I decided to go over the 100+ lines of code comprising the function for the umpteenth time, finally spotting the single word in the code that was causing the error.

Just a single time in the entire block of code, I had accidentally written

```
title
```

Instead of

```
passedTitle
```

Whilst my problem is fixed, this still begs the question:

**Does an SQL function share a namespace with the SELECT statement calling it?**

Comment: Can you post body of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Does an SQL function share a namespace with the SELECT statement calling it?*

As per your function signature definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION removeYear(passedTitle CHAR(255), passedYear CHAR(100))
RETURNS CHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
```

Value of first parameter is ***always*** identified within the function body using its name ***`passedTitle`*** only.

And this is applicable to any parameter or variable declared defined within any stored procedure.

And hence if you use `title` as name for the first parameter over its defined name `passedTitle` in the signature, engine won't recognise it runtime and throws an error.